# Convert Base64 string into Integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, base64

I'd like to convert Base64 values such as "AAAAAAAAABI=" to their corresponding integer.  I fussed around with Base64.decode64, but it was not obvious how it would be part of the solution.

```
irb > require 'base64'
 => true 
irb > Base64.decode64('AAAAAAAAABI=')
 => "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12"
```

Comment: Heh! It converted the first 'A' into its binary equivalent (displayed as hex 12) and stored it in the low-order octet of a 64-bit int. You might find that there are 12 (decimal) more 64-bit ints stored right after that first one. If you don't see them, can you somehow make that happen? That would give you a better view into what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you're after. If not, take a look at [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-unpack) for more information about what it can do.

```
require 'base64'
i = Base64.decode64('AAAAAAAAABI=')
i.unpack('q*').first
# => 1297036692682702848
```

Comment: If you are going to use `unpack`, then you can get rid of the base64 library and do it entirely using `unpack`; actually, `Base64.decode64` is implemented as `unpack("m").first`, so your code is equivalent to `'AAAAAAAAABI='.unpack('m').first.unpack('q*').first`.